# How to solve eas update problem in expo project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to update my build with `eas update`
but when I run the command this error shows up:

```
[expo-cli] TypeError: (0 , _minimatch).default is not a function
```

I am trying to use `eas update` and I use it for another app and it works fine.

How do I fix this?